# When plotting heatmap using ggplot2, how can I gave NA data a shape

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, heatmap

I am using ggplot2 to generate a heatmap like this

[image]

I use code like this

```
ggplot(meltdata, aes(variable, ids)) +  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())+
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) 
  + scale_x_discrete(labels=NULL,expand = c(0, 0)) 
  + labs(x = "",y = "") 
  + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),colour = "white") 
  + scale_fill_gradient2(na.value ="black",midpoint = -log(0.05,10),
  +high = "red", low = "steelblue",guide="colourbar")
```

So far I get my plot like this

[image]

My question is that is there anyway I can change my NA data points (which is black in my plot) with a shape of cross like that in the first plot.
A less important question is that can I make my color more rainbowish like that first plot instead just blue and red?